# Apply all filters/sortby to Mage::getModel

Tags: magento-1.9

How do I use the filters that the user set in the toolbar, when I load my product like this:

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($childId)
                 ->getProductCollection()
                 ->addAttributeToSelect('*') // add all attributes - optional
                 ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1) // enabled
                 ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4) //visibility in catalog,search
                 ->setOrder('price', 'ASC'); //sets the order by price
```

But by default it loads all the products like this:

```
$_productCollection = $this->getLoadedProductCollection();
```

The default method reads all the options somehow.
Can't I do that too with my method.

The only restriction is that I have to load the products by a category ID.

Comment: YOu want to load products based on category id..

Comment: @Kothari Yes, exactly. But I also want to apply filters like `setPageSize`,  `setCurPage`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
public function _getProductCollection()
{
    $categoryId = "Your Id Here";
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
    $_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addCategoryFilter($category)
        ->addAttributeToFilter('status', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
        ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH)
        ->setPageSize(20)
        ->setCurPage(1)
        ->joinField('is_in_stock',
            'cataloginventory/stock_item',
            'is_in_stock',
            'product_id=entity_id',
            'is_in_stock=1',
            '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
            'left');

    return $_productCollection;
}
```

For page count check this link `https://www.creare.co.uk/blog/magento/limiting-collection-size-in-magento`

Comment: Users can set the `pageSize` themself through the toolbar, how do I get the selected `pageSize`?